# Deleting a directory + unlinking the files

Tags: 13.04, files, directory, symbolic-link

I have a folder with many files those have a few sym links pointing to them like

```
/some_path -> /dir/file1
/some_path2 -> /dir/file2
/some_path3 -> /dir/file3
```

But I don't remember neither the `some_path`s no which files from `dir` have sym links pointing to them.

Now I need to delete `dir` (I really need it for some reason). And I also want no file to point to any file from `dir` since I'll delete it.

How do I *unlink* those files? What if I just delete `dir`, will they unlink by themselves?

Answer (score 0):

To unlink files,

```
unlink /path/to/the/link_file
```

If you delete the `dir` it doesn't unlink themselves.And if you click on the link after `deleting dir`,it will shows like this,

[image]

Comment: what's /path/to/the/link_file according my question: /some_path or /dir/file1?

Comment: you doesn't know where the link was located.

Comment: no, I don't. So how can I unlink /path/to/the/link_file then if I don't know what /path/to/the/link_file is ?

Comment: If a link was created on Downloads folder for an avinash folder in desktop.Then removing the link by running this command. unlink ~/Downloads/avinash

Comment: I know only path to dir and nothing else.

Comment: See this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39333/how-can-i-remove-all-symbolic-links-with-a-special-target

Answer (score 0):

If `somepath`s are in the same location and assuming they are on the same filesystem as `/dir`, we could make a guess and use [Dennis Williamson's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4535344/3701431) approach

```
find -L / -xdev -samefile /dir/file1
```

So assuming `/dir/file1` is original and say `/opt/foo` is symlink, this command should traverse `/` without crossing `/`'s filesystem boundaries and find all files that are the same as original. That would include symlinks and hard links.

We could also use `lname` to see if contents of symlink point to `/dir/file1`

```
find -lname "*passwd*"
```

However, more reasonable approach would probably be to either move or delete `dir` first, and then look for broken symlinks as suggested by the [user rozcietrzewiacz's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38691/85039) on the relevant post

```
find / -xdev -type l ! -exec test -e {} \; -print
```

If you intent to get rid of those broken symlink, you can use `-delete` flag as well